# New Coffeescript file interfering with other JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

In my app I use the below code to give expand/collapse capabilities.

In one of my .js files:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.row .bundle').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
        $collapse.collapse('toggle');
    });

});
```

In the view, surrounding whatever I want to expand:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align:center">
 <div class="collapse-group">
    <h4 class="normal_links">
        <a class="bundle" href='#'>(Expand)</a>
    </h4><br>
  <div class="collapse normal_links" >
    # Code to expand/collapse here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Worked like a charm until I started using the morris.js library to introduce some charts to my app, at which point the expand/collapse (henceforce EC) functionality stopped working on every page OTHER than the one on which my charts show.  When I say EC doesn't work, I mean that when I click the expand link, it just follows it to '#'.

My morris.js code, in the animal.js.coffee file of the model to which the charts belong:

```
jQuery ->
Morris.Donut
  element: 'weight_chart'
  data: [
    {label: "Pounds Sold", value: $('#weight_chart').data('sold')}
    {label: "Pounds Left", value: $('#weight_chart').data('left')}
  ]
  colors: ['#0066CC', "#880000"]

Morris.Donut
  element: 'sales_chart'
  data: [
    {label: "Revenue Made", value: $('#sales_chart').data('sold')}
    {label: "Est. Revenue Left", value: $('#sales_chart').data('left')}
  ]
  colors: ["#336633", "#880000"]

Morris.Donut
    element: 'status_chart'
    data: [
        {label: "Incomplete", value: $('#status_chart').data('zero')}
        {label: "Downpaid", value: $('#status_chart').data('one')}
        {label: "Fully Paid", value: $('#status_chart').data('two')}
        {label: "Received", value: $('#status_chart').data('three')}
    ]
    colors: ["#880000", '#E09050', '#989898', '#000000' ]
```

An example of how I actually call the chart in the view:

```
 <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "sales_chart", 
       data: {sold: @animal.rev.round(2), 
              left: @animal.rev_left.round(2)}, 
       class: "morris_chart" %>
```

The charts display perfectly, as does the EC on the page with the charts. On seemingly every other page, not. And when I delete the animal.js.coffee file with the morris code (temporarily), the problem goes away. I've triple checked my view code, and it's all good (or at least identical to the code that is working).

Possibly of additional interest is that back when this worked there used to be an empty animal.js file, and I replaced it with a animal.js.coffee file with the morris-relevant code. The actual morris.js and raphael.js code is in vendors/javascripts. The EC javascript code is in the .js file of another model entirely, but that hasn't been a problem up to this point.

Any ideas? I'll be away from my computer for a few hours, but when I'm back I'll post any additional code anybody wants.

EDIT -- Figured my application.js file might also be relevant:

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require raphael
//= require morris
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you try only including the morris.js file in only the view that you're doing the charts instead of adding it to your application js file? If that fixes your collapses, its a problem with Morris, in which you should open an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/oesmith/morris.js/issues)

Comment: Is that your real indentation in the CoffeeScript file?

Comment: Yes it is! I haven't learned coffeescript, and just copied some from a railscast and added some lines/formatting of my own. Is it a whitespace language? Did I mess that up? I'll give Magicmarkker's suggestion a shot, but it sounds like if I formatted it wrong that might be related to the problem, so I'll look at that too. Any specific things I'm screwing up in the formatting?

Comment: It is a whitespace language, and that's probably not doing what you want.  You probably want to indent everything except the `jQuery ->` line once.  Look at [this](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try:jQuery%20-%3E%0Ahi()%0A%0AjQuery%20-%3E%0A%20%20hi()) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to have been that the Coffeescript was looking for the elements ("sales_chart", etc) on pages where it did not appear. When that happened, things went wrong, and none of my other Javascript worked. To fix this, all I had to do was check for the element before calling Morris on it. So:

```
jQuery ->

    if $('#weight_chart').length
      Morris.Donut
        element: 'weight_chart'
        data: [
          {label: "Pounds Sold", value: $('#weight_chart').data('sold')}
          {label: "Pounds Left", value: $('#weight_chart').data('left')}
        ]
        colors: ['#0066CC', "#880000"]

    if $('#sales_chart').length
      Morris.Donut
        element: 'sales_chart'
        data: [
          {label: "Revenue Made", value: $('#sales_chart').data('sold')}
          {label: "Est. Revenue Left", value: $('#sales_chart').data('left')}
        ]
        colors: ["#336633", "#880000"]

    if $('#status_chart').length
      Morris.Donut
        element: 'status_chart'
        data: [
          {label: "Incomplete", value: $('#status_chart').data('zero')}
          {label: "Downpaid", value: $('#status_chart').data('one')}
          {label: "Fully Paid", value: $('#status_chart').data('two')}
          {label: "Received", value: $('#status_chart').data('three')}
        ]
        colors: ["#880000", '#E09050', '#989898', '#000000']
```

Problem solved. Thanks for the help, and the excuse to learn Coffeescript!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your animal.js.coffee to this, which has the correct indentation to place your Morris calls inside the function you're passing to jQuery.

```
jQuery ->
  Morris.Donut
    element: 'weight_chart'
    data: [
      {label: "Pounds Sold", value: $('#weight_chart').data('sold')}
      {label: "Pounds Left", value: $('#weight_chart').data('left')}
    ]
    colors: ['#0066CC', "#880000"]

  Morris.Donut
    element: 'sales_chart'
    data: [
      {label: "Revenue Made", value: $('#sales_chart').data('sold')}
      {label: "Est. Revenue Left", value: $('#sales_chart').data('left')}
    ]
    colors: ["#336633", "#880000"]

  Morris.Donut
    element: 'status_chart'
    data: [
        {label: "Incomplete", value: $('#status_chart').data('zero')}
        {label: "Downpaid", value: $('#status_chart').data('one')}
        {label: "Fully Paid", value: $('#status_chart').data('two')}
        {label: "Received", value: $('#status_chart').data('three')}
    ]
    colors: ["#880000", '#E09050', '#989898', '#000000' ]
```

Comment: Huh. Reformatted as suggested, but now (or maybe before now as well, but definitely now), it a) still doesn't work on the pages without the charts, and b) doesn't even work on the charts page?!?! Yuck.

Comment: Yeah. It seems more and more like this is a coffeescript formatting error. I pasted some of the original js code into js2coffee.org and it spat out something very different from what I formatted. I'll dive into coffeescript and sort this one out, then paste the formatting that ended up working for me. (I think the $ labels are also a problem). Thanks for all the help, everybody!